# Tensor product of finite type UFD algebras over an algebraically closed field is again UFD?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products, unique-factorization-domains

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $A$ and $B$ two finite type $K$-algebras which are assumed to be UFD. Is $A \otimes_K B$ again a UFD?

This question has been already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578801/is-the-tensor-product-of-ufds-again-ufd) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293027/tensor-product-of-ufds), but no (convincing) answer was given. I would like to add a few examples to show that the answer might be slightly less standard than it appears.

$\bullet$ <s>If we drop the *finite type* assumption, the result is wrong. Indeed, take $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{A = K[[T]]}$ and $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{B = K[X,Y,Z]\Big/ \left(X^5 + Y^7-Z^2 \right)}$. Then Samuel proves in his lecture notes [Lecture on unique factorization domains](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr30.pdf) that $A$ and $B$ are UFD (see Theorem 8.1 in chapter 1 and Theorem 2.1 in chapter 2). On the other hand, he also proves that $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{A \otimes_K B = B[[T]]}$ is not a UFD (see Theorem 9.1 in chapter 1).</s>
**Edit** : as mentionned by Friedrich Knop, $A \otimes_K B$ is only a subalgebra of $B[[T]]$ (my stupid mistake) and so it's not clear wether it is a UFD or not.

$\bullet$ Even with the finite type assumption, the result doesn't seem to be known (at least at the time when Samuel wrote his lecture notes). Indeed, he states his Theorem 8.1 as:

*Let $A$ be a UFD and $A[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ be graded by assigning weights $\omega_i$ to $X_i$ ($\omega_i >0)$. Let $F(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be an irreducible homogeneous (for the grading) polynomial, $c$ be a positive integer, prime to the degree of $F$, and*:
$$B = A[X_1,\ldots,X_n,Z] \Big/ \left(Z^c-F \right).$$
*Then $B$ is a UFD if one of the following conditions is satisfied:*

1. $c \equiv 1 \ [\omega]$
2. *Every finitely generated projective $A$-module is free.*

If Samuel knew that the tensor product of two finite type $K$-algebras (with $K$ algebraically closed) which are UFD is again a UFD, he would certainly have mentionned that:
$$B = A[X_1,\ldots,X_n,Z] \Big/ \left(Z^c-F \right) = A \otimes_K K[X_1, \ldots, X_n,Z]\Big/(Z^c-F)$$
is always a UFD when $A$ is a UFD which is a finite type algebra over $K$ algebraically closed (and he doesn't). At the end of the lecture notes, he gives various examples of such rings which are not UFD, but I can't find one where $K$ is an algebraically closed field and the second condition is the one that is not satisfied.

All in all, I would be very grateful to have a definitive answer on the initial question (even with a highly technological argument or counter-example).

Comment: Note that $A\otimes_KB$ is smaller than $B[[T]]$. It consists of those power series whose coefficients span a finite dimensional $K$-vector space.

Comment: @KevinCasto : I don't think there are any obvious connection.

Comment: For a partial result, I think that this is true if $K$ is uncountable of char 0. First, you can WLOG shrink $Spec(A)$ and $Spec(B)$. Indeed, we want to show that $Pic(Spec(A \otimes B) = Pic(Spec(A)) \times Pic(Spec(B)$. By https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493005/picard-group-of-product-of-spaces, this happens if and only if the restriction of every line bundle in $Pic(Spec(A \otimes B)$ to $Spec(k(A) \otimes k(B)$ is trivial. We can check this by first restricting to the product of some dense opens in $Spec(A)$ and $Spec(B)$.

Comment: After shrinking $Spec(A)$ and $Spec(B)$ (localizing), we may assume without loss of generality that $A$ and $B$ are regular. Then you can embed $Spec(A)$ and $Spec(B)$ as opens in smooth projective varieties $X,Y$. The fact that $X,Y$ have opens that are local factorization domains imply by the short exact sequence for Picard groups that their Picard group is finitely generated (by codim 1 components of the complement of the open).

Comment: This means that Jac(X) = Jac(Y) must be trivial (if the Jacobians had positive dimension then it would have uncountably many points, contradicting the finite generation of Picard). Once you know that one of the Jacobians of X or Y is trivial, a see-saw type argument shows that $Pic(X \times Y) = Pic(X) \times Pic(Y)$. Now, if you have a line bundle on $Spec(A \otimes B)$, you can extend it to a line bundle on $Pic(X \times Y)$ (this is where smoothness of the compactification is important).

Comment: This comes from a line bundle in $Pic(X) \times Pic(Y)$, which by restriction yields a line bundle on $Pic(Spec(A)) \times Pic(Spec(B))$. Since $A$ and $B$ are UFD's, this line bundle must be trivial, as desired.

Comment: @afh : that might be easy, but I don't see the connection with my question. If $B = A = K[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ then $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ is a smooth compactification of $\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \mathrm{Spec}(B) = \mathbb{A}^n$. It clear that $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{P}^n) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, but I don't see how you get from that the equality $\mathrm{Pic}(A \otimes_K B) = 0$...

Comment: What I was thinking:  if you have a line bundle L on $A\otimes B$, then you can extend to a line bundle M on $X\times Y$ (view L as a Weil divisor, this will induce a line bundle on $X\times Y$ by smoothness). Then you know that $M= H \otimes N$ for some line bundles H,N on X,Y respectively. Restrict this back to $A\otimes B$ and you conclude that L is a tensor product $H_A \otimes N_B$ of the restrictions to A and B respectively. Since both A,B are UFDs, $H_A$ and $N_B$ are trivial. So their tensor L is trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433662/82179) gives a partial result under some additional hypotheses, but these are not needed.

**Theorem** (Boissière–Gabber–Serman). *If $X$ and $Y$ are locally factorial varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$, then so is $X \times Y$. If $\operatorname{Cl}(X) = \operatorname{Cl}(Y) = 0$, then $\operatorname{Cl}(X \times Y)=0$.*

See [BGS, Thm. 5.1 and Cor. 5.4]. $\square$

Taking $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y = \operatorname{Spec} B$ for unique factorisation domains $A$ and $B$ shows that $A \otimes_k B$ is a unique factorisation domain.

---

**References.**

[BGS] S. Boissière, O. Gabber, O. Serman, *Sur le produit de variétés factorielles ou $\mathbf Q$-factorielles*. Preprint (2011). arXiv:[1104.1861](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1861).

Comment: Thank you so much Remy! I have been looking for days on scholar for such a paper and i couldnt find it. That is such a relief, thanks again!

Comment: I suppose it didn't show up because this is still a preprint for some reason. That means it's not peer reviewed, and normally I would exercise some caution. That said, Gabber is one of the most careful mathematicians around, so having him as a coauthor is probably at least as good as peer review...

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $A$ is a UFD if and only if $A$ is a normal domain with $\operatorname{Cl}(A) = 0$. The tensor product of normal domains over an algebraically closed field is a normal domain [Tags [06DF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06DF) and [09P9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09P9)], so the question is about the class group. I will write $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $V = \operatorname{Spec} B$ and treat the more general case of normal varieties with $\operatorname{Cl}(U) = \operatorname{Cl}(V) = 0$.

When $U$ is locally factorial, we get $\operatorname{Cl}(U) \cong \operatorname{Pic}(U)$, and the question becomes substantially easier. Here is a positive result when $U$ and $V$ are locally factorial and admit compactifications $X$ and $Y$ that are locally factorial. (It seems that Mohan was already aware of this, at least in the smooth case, in the [cited Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3578801), but no details were provided.)

**Lemma.** *If $X$ and $Y$ are proper and locally factorial varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ are dense open subschemes with $\operatorname{Pic}(U) = \operatorname{Pic}(V) = 0$, then $\operatorname{Pic}(U \times V) = 0$.*

*Proof.* The Picard schemes $\mathbf{Pic}_X$ and $\mathbf{Pic}_Y$ are representable, and there is an isomorphism
$$\mathbf{Pic}_{X\times Y}\cong\mathbf{Pic}_X\times\mathbf{Pic}_Y\times\mathbf{Hom}(\mathbf{Alb}_X,\mathbf{Pic}^0_Y).$$
(See for instance §4.4 of my dissertation [vDdB] for details and further references.) Denote the complements of $U$ and $V$ by $D$ and $E$ respectively (they may or may not be divisors). Writing $d = \dim X$ and $e = \dim Y$, we get exact sequences [Fulton, Prop. 1.8] (see also [Hartshorne, Prop. II.6.5])
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{CH}_{d-1}(D) &\to \operatorname{Cl}(X) \to \operatorname{Cl}(U) \to 0,\\
\operatorname{CH}_{e-1}(E) &\to \operatorname{Cl}(Y) \to \operatorname{Cl}(V) \to 0.
\end{align*}
Since $\operatorname{Cl}(U) = \operatorname{Cl}(V) = 0$ and $\operatorname{CH}_{d-1}(D)$ and $\operatorname{CH}_{e-1}(E)$ are finitely generated (by the cycle classes of the codimension $1$ components), we conclude that $\operatorname{Cl}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(Y)$ are finitely generated. In particular, $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$ and $\operatorname{Pic}^0(Y)$ are finitely generated, so they have to vanish since a positive-dimensional commutative group scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ has infinitely many torsion elements (and infinite rank if $k \not\cong \bar{\mathbf F}_p$). Thus we see $\operatorname{Pic}(X \times Y) \cong \operatorname{Pic}(X) \times \operatorname{Pic}(Y)$. Again the sequence [Fulton, Prop. 1.8] gives
$$\operatorname{CH}_{d+e-1}\big((X \times Y) \setminus (U \times V)\Big) \to \operatorname{Pic}(X \times Y) \to \operatorname{Pic}(U \times V) \to 0.$$
But if the divisorial components of $D$ and $E$ are $D_1,\ldots,D_m$ and $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ respectively, then the codimension $1$ components of $X \times Y \setminus U \times V$ are $D_1 \times Y, \ldots, D_m \times Y$ and $X \times E_1, \ldots, X \times E_n$. These generate $\operatorname{Pic}(X \times Y)$, so we conclude that $\operatorname{Pic}(U \times V) = 0$. $\square$

---

**References.**

[Fulton]  W. Fulton, [*Intersection theory*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1700-8). Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete **2**. Springer-Verlag, 1984.

[Hartshorne]  R. Hartshorne, [*Algebraic geometry*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0). Graduate Texts in Mathematics **52**. Springer-Verlag, 1983.

[vDdB]  R. van Dobben de Bruyn, [*Dominating varieties by liftable ones*](https://doi.org/10.7916/D89K5TB0). PhD Thesis, Columbia University, 2018.

Comment: Hmm, the cited isomorphism for $\mathbf{Pic}_{X \times Y}$ in [vDdB] only applies if you know that $(\mathbf{Pic}^0_X)^{\text{red}}$ and $(\mathbf{Pic}^0_Y)^{\text{red}}$ are abelian varieties, but that's ok in this case as they are actually both trivial.

Comment: $G_a$ doesn't have a lot of torsion in char 0, but it is not finitely generated either. I think that every group of positive dimension over algebraically closed field will contain either $G_a$, $G_m$ or abelian variety, so we should be ok by those cases.

Comment: Interesting answer. Though I'd like to know when $U$ and $V$ admit locally factorial compactifications. Is it true in char $0$?

Comment: @afh thanks, you're right. At any rate, no positive-dimensional connected commutative algebraic group over an algebraically closed field is finitely generated. Any $G$ is an extension $0 \to H \to G \to A \to 0$ with $A$ abelian and $H \cong G_u \times G_m$ with $G_u$ unipotent and $G_m$ a torus. See for instance Theorems 10.25 and 17.17 in [Milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf).

Comment: @Libli I just realised I didn't check whether $X \times Y$ is still locally factorial, and looking up a proof led me to a paper that actually shows the entire thing you want. I have added this as a [new answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433678/82179) (keeping up the existing one as it may be of interest).